# Voltage drop from pin to end of connectors

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

[image]I have Raspberry Pi 3 Model B v1.2 and it has booted. When I check the voltage between pin 2 to pin 6, it is around 4.85 V.

But when I connect connectors and then check the voltage at connector ends it is around 0.5 V.

Can somebody help me to find the issue with this?

Comment: The issue is you are connecting the connectors wrongly or those connectors are not intended to be used with the Pi.  A photo would help.  I suggest you don't power the Pi when those connectors are fitted.

Comment: Though in the image connectors are connect to pin 2 and pin 14, result is same.

Comment: That's not what I thought you were doing.  That should be fine.  The only reason not to read the supply voltage (5V) would be a poor connection or the wrong pin.  Perhaps try between 2 and 6 or 4 and 6.

Comment: It is same behavior on other pins too.

Comment: There are two possibilities. 1) you are not connecting to the correct pins. 2) You have a broken voltmeter (perhaps it needs a new battery).

Comment: Hi Joan. I just checked the conductivity of the connectors. Resistance turned out to be infinite. Somehow my connectors which were purchased at-least a year back started failing. I checked all connectors and turn out to be same case with almost everyone, though 1-2 connectors worked. 
Is there a possibility that connector over period get damaged internally?

Comment: Well yours have!  I have not heard of such a thing before, but I'm just a hobbyist.

Comment: Me too.. This is weird. I am going to get in bottom of this.